# I want to close the offer at the end of the timer?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the ad to close automatically when the timer ends I have tried several forms of loops but it still doesn't work when implementing the loops it stops working, it just cancels the timer thing.

The other thing I couldn't do is when I press the close button I want the ad to close.

```js
//This is the timer code
function paddedFormat(num) {
    return num < 10 ? "0" + num : num;
}

function startCountDown(duration, element) {
    let secondsRemaining = duration;
    let min = 0;
    let sec = 0;

    let countInterval = setInterval(function () {
        sec = parseInt(secondsRemaining % 60);
        element.textContent = `${paddedFormat(sec)}`;
        secondsRemaining = secondsRemaining - 1;
        if (secondsRemaining < 0) { clearInterval(countInterval) };
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    let time_minutes = 0; // Value in minutes
    let time_seconds = 9; // Value in seconds

    let duration = time_seconds + 1 ;

    element = document.querySelector('#count-down-timer');
    element.textContent = `${paddedFormat(time_minutes)}:${paddedFormat(time_seconds)}`;

    startCountDown(--duration, element);
};
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 4.0em;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.ad {
    display: flex;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: rgb(23, 29, 29);
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgb(253, 253, 0);
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
header {
    display: flex;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: rgb(94, 111, 185);
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
.cerrar {
    margin-top: -10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
.logo {
    font-family: Brush Script MT;
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: left;
    color: azure;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
nav a {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
nav a:hover {
    color: black;
}

.root {
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 193px;
    height: 109px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    border: solid 20px rgb(94, 111, 185);
}

@media (max-width:500px) {
    header {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    nav {
        padding: 10px 0px;
    }
}
.alert {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: solid 5px green;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.text-center {
    background-color: rgb(0, 4, 255);
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 105px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 35rem;
    color: red;
}
.segundo_parr {
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.color {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 3.0em;
}
```

```html
<!--I want this not to be erased-->
    <div class="ad">
        <h1> 10% discount</h1>
    </div>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <h2 class="name">Entornos web</h2>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Offers</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Products</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">register</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="create">

    </div>

    <!--I want all this to close when I press the close button. -->
    <div class="alert">
        <h1 class="color">YOU HAVE A PROMOTION AND IT ENDS IN
            <!--This is the button to close the announcement-->
            <a href="" class="boton close">
                <img src="img/close.ico" alt="">
            </a>
        </h1>

        <!--Este es el temporizador, quiero que se cierre cuando el contador llegue a 0.-->
        <h1 class="text-center" id="count-down-timer"></h1>

        <h1 class="color segundo_parr">SECONDS, CLICK ON OFFERS NOW!</h1>
    </div>
```

the other thing I couldn't do is when I press the close button I want the ad to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.querySelector(".alert")` and `.remove()` to remove that Ads from HTML like [@Nathan Adda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72330906/19117401) suggest, `addEventListener` click on DOM of close Button for  remove Ads using `.remove()` same above:

```js
const ads = document.querySelector(".alert")
const closeButton = document.querySelector(".close")
//This is the timer code
function paddedFormat(num) {
    return num < 10 ? "0" + num : num;
}

function startCountDown(duration, element) {
    
    let secondsRemaining = duration;
    let min = 0;
    let sec = 0;

    let countInterval = setInterval(function () {

        
        sec = parseInt(secondsRemaining % 60);

        element.textContent = `${paddedFormat(sec)}`;

        secondsRemaining = secondsRemaining - 1;
        if (secondsRemaining < 0) { 
          clearInterval(countInterval)
          if(ads){
            ads.remove();
           } 
         };

    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    let time_minutes = 0; // Value in minutes
    let time_seconds = 9; // Value in seconds

    let duration = time_seconds + 1 ;

    element = document.querySelector('#count-down-timer');
    element.textContent = `${paddedFormat(time_minutes)}:${paddedFormat(time_seconds)}`;

    startCountDown(--duration, element);
};

function closeAd(){ads.remove()}
if(closeButton) closeButton.addEventListener("click", closeAd)
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 4.0em;
    margin-left: 30px;

}

.ad {
    display: flex;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: rgb(23, 29, 29);
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgb(253, 253, 0);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: rgb(94, 111, 185);
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.cerrar {
    margin-top: -10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.logo {
    font-family: Brush Script MT;
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: left;
    color: azure;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

nav a {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: black;
}


.root {
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 193px;
    height: 109px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    border: solid 20px rgb(94, 111, 185);
}

@media (max-width:500px) {
    header {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    nav {
        padding: 10px 0px;
    }
}


.alert {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: solid 5px green;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.text-center {
    background-color: rgb(0, 4, 255);
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 105px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 35rem;
    color: red;
}

.segundo_parr {
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.color {

    color: blue;
    font-size: 3.0em;
}
```

```html
<!--I want this not to be erased-->
    <div class="ad">
        <h1> 10% discount</h1>

    </div>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <h2 class="name">Entornos web</h2>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Offers</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Products</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">register</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="create">

    </div>

    <!--I want all this to close when I press the close button. -->
    <div class="alert">
        <h1 class="color">YOU HAVE A PROMOTION AND IT ENDS IN
            <!--This is the button to close the announcement-->
            <a class="boton close">
                <img src="img/close.ico" alt="">
            </a>
        </h1>

        <!--Este es el temporizador, quiero que se cierre cuando el contador llegue a 0.-->
        <h1 class="text-center" id="count-down-timer"></h1>

        <h1 class="color segundo_parr">SECONDS, CLICK ON OFFERS NOW!</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an id to the div you want to be deleted then

delete the element directly at the end of the timer with this function or another:

document.getElementById("elToDelete").remove();

Maybe use the .then of a time to insert that part